# Add in get triggered only by site collection administrator and not by user

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, csom, remote-event-receiver

My scenario:

I have created a remote event receiver that triggers on a new item added,note everything works well when i use my site collection admin account.

when i create a user(note a guest user from azure AD) giving him full control on sharepoint site thought. when this user add an item nothing happens!!!

Comment: I did figure out what happened, the add in had site collection permission and the user had only basic permissions.

Answer (score 1):

I did figure out what happened, the add in had site collection permission and the user had only basic permissions. You just have to change the permission level in app manifest.